# How can I install two products with one Inno Setup script?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have  two products: a Client and an Admin product. There may be a case when the user wants to install one, the other, or both. How do I do this in Inno Setup?

I am relatively new to Inno Setup. I have tried to use `Components` and `Types` but so far only get a dropdown of single choices. I would like a set of checkboxes (or whatever) that allow the user to select what they are installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`[Types]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection), configure one custom type (the `iscustom` flag).

Then in the [`Components` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection), add two components for the custom installation.

```
[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: client; Description: "Client product"; Types: custom
Name: admin; Description: "Admin product"; Types: custom

[Files]
Source: "client.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: client
Source: "admin.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: admin
```

[image: Select components page]

---

An alternative to the `iscustom` setup type is using the [`AlwaysShowComponentsList`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_alwaysshowcomponentslist) directive.