# InnoSetup - multiple installs of same product with different options

Tags: windows, service, inno-setup

I'm trying to create an installer that will allow me to install the same product but with different options each time.  I appreciate this opens something of a can of worms but wondered if there were any ways this could be achieved.

The product installs a number of DLLs and a .exe and then creates a service with a name based on the selected options.  A second install (with different options) would create another service with a different name (but ideally share the same dlls & .exe) and create a separate entry in the "Add and Remove Programs" list.  When one is removed then the appropriate service is stopped and removed but the files remain until the last install is removed in which case then the files are removed also.

I know this sounds like a lot to ask and it may be easier just to create a number of different installers.

Thanks

Steve H

Comment: See [How can I install two products with one Inno Setup script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33156723/850848) or [Inno Setup sub-options/sub-components for different setup types (server/client)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58539344/850848).